# Como fazer um único botão liga e desliga e no clique enviar valor na URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

No código abaixo a cada tenho dois forms um para enviar o valor 1 e outro para enviar 0 e ambos os forms enviar este valor via GET

Quando envio o GET **STATUS BOMBA N°1::="motor":** recebe o retorno do CLP

STATUS BOMBA N°1::=**true**

STATUS BOMBA N°1::=**false**

**Ligar**

/index2.html?"motor"=1

**Desligar**

/index2.html?"motor"=0

**Como faço para fazer um único botão enviar via GET e mudar o texto do botão para Liga e Desligar ?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Liga Desliga</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="LIGA">
                <input type="hidden" name='"motor"' value ="1">
            </p>
        </form>

        <form>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="DESLIGA">
                <input type="hidden" name='"motor"' value ="0">
            </p>
        </form>

        STATUS BOMBA N°1::="motor":

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tem como fazer no client, mas eu faria pelo lado do servidor. Fazer via javascript ia ser meio chatinho porque toda vez que a pagina será carregada, o javascript também sera recarregado.

Comment: @Francisco eu sei que quando envio o valor recebo um RETORNO nesta variável dentro do próprio html STATUS BOMBA N°1::="motor": True ou False ai dá para fazer a lógica.

Comment: Não entendi kk. Teria como colocar o exemplo disso na sua pergunta?

Comment: @Francisco esta página html é inserida dentro de um CLP, isto é ao invés de hospedar em uma hosting, eu hospedo no CLP e neste CLP tem banco de dados, então quando envio um comando recebo uma resposta e esta resposta recebo nesta tag "motor" entendeu isto que dizer que o name do input recebe uma valor. entendeu ?

Comment: @Francisco o name='"motor"' pega o valor vindo do CLP ai isto fica assim STATUS BOMBA N°1::=true ou STATUS BOMBA N°1::=false

Comment: Que linguagem seria esta que está usando?

Comment: A programação dentro do CLP é LADDER é uma linguagem onde o programador arrasta e solta a lógica https://www.citisystems.com.br/linguagem-ladder/ agora o CLP é bem interessante a metodologia em relação às variáveis de captura e envio, nada anormal, mas pega agente de surpresa, ai tem que estudar bastante para entender. confira um tutorial do CLP Siemens S7 1200 https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8567/siemens-s7-1200-web-server-tutorial--from-getting-started-to-html5-user-defined-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for possível a adição de um `script` na página, você pode tentar algo como o desenvolvido no código abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Liga Desliga</title>
        <script>
            var motorStatus = parseInt(decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substr(1)).split('=')[1] || 0);

            window.onload = function(){
                if(motorStatus == 0){
                    document.querySelector('form[name="controlador"] input[type="submit"]').value = 'LIGA';
                    document.querySelector('form[name="controlador"] input[type="hidden"]').value = '1';
                } else{
                    document.querySelector('form[name="controlador"] input[type="submit"]').value = 'DESLIGA';
                    document.querySelector('form[name="controlador"] input[type="hidden"]').value = '0';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="controlador">
            <input type="submit" value="LIGA">
            <input type="hidden" name='"motor"' value ="1">
        </form>
        STATUS BOMBA N°1::="motor":
    </body>
</html>
```